# How to keep parameters after login (wordpress)?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, url

When customers get a quote, they click 'accept' button.
Then a broswer opens with the following URL.

```
https://www.mywep.com/ko/my-checkout/order-pay/12723/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_p185585ca050098139&request_quote=123&status=accepted&raq_nonce=fbdjui8a2c59141c359bjgfyc0a613fd&lang=jp
```

When the customer click the accept button while logging in, the link shows check-out page, so it works well.
The problem is when the user hasn't been logged in.
As soon as the user login, all the prameters disappear, and shows the following URL, 
which occurs error message 'Sorry, This Order Is Invalid And Cannot Be Paid For.'.

```
https://www.mywep.com/ko/my-account/view-quote/12712/
```

The URL was created by YITH plugin.
Would you please let me know how to keep the parameter after login?

Thank you.`enter code here`

Comment: How do the user log in after accepting the quote? Does it redirect automatically on the login page, or do they have to click a login button manually? If it is a button, you can dynamically get the current query vars and apply it to the button element using jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: Hello, users have to click the login button (class:mylogin) and login popup appears. It's YITH's popup login that pops up the login where the class name is mylogin. Thank you for your help iismaell.